# Drupal 6 site not sending password reset emails

Tags: users

The password reset emails for a Drupal 6 site I'm working on aren't getting to our users' inboxes. The emails aren't being blocked by spam filters, and according to the site logs at admin/reports/dblog the emails are being sent. How can I go about debugging this?

Answer (score 1):

Are other kinds of mails correctly sent, or are ALL mails from the senong site discarded ?

If other mails are sent from the same server/site, then something's wrong with the Drupal installation.

If they're not and the sending server's logs are indicating a correct sending, then I'd check the destination server logs to see what's happening here. Sometimes mails got discarded for voodoo reasons, like blacklisting (which is not the same as spam detection) etc.